# SMART LOG Guide

Tags: boot, hard-disk, smartctl

I have  a dual boot linux(KDE 20 lts) and Windows 10 system. I have started getting frequent boot errors(A Quick message containing some I/O error, Unable to boot windows,linux and grub) in my startup that re-corrects itself after reboot.

I did a short SMART test on my system disk (`/dev/sda`). Kindly guide me on identifying and resolving it Here is the [link to paste-bin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mNp9X4ktrX/) (bootinfo by grub)

```
**SMART REPORT(SHORT TEST)**


...
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-50-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   204   204   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       6704
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       7267
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       5151
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       348
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       171547
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   166   166   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 9/49)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 32 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 32 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7265 hours (302 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 81 37 b4 60 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0060b437 = 6337591

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 c0 58 f8 b3 60 40 00      00:01:15.846  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 c0 50 b8 a1 60 40 00      00:01:15.831  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 48 48 b0 cd 60 40 00      00:01:15.831  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 40 e0 0c 14 40 00      00:01:15.816  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 48 38 40 8d 60 40 00      00:01:15.816  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 31 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7265 hours (302 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 61 33 89 07  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x07893361 = 126432097

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 02 90 60 33 89 40 00      01:06:25.973  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 0b 88 d0 ff d6 40 00      01:06:25.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 d0 fe d6 40 00      01:06:25.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 9f 78 a8 53 e4 40 00      01:06:25.936  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 c2 70 b0 fb d6 40 00      01:06:25.929  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 30 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7264 hours (302 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 11 7f da df 02  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x02dfda7f = 48224895

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 50 98 40 da df 40 00      00:01:48.485  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 90 ca 4c 20 40 00      00:01:48.459  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 58 88 e8 d9 df 40 00      00:01:48.449  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 80 ea 0d 27 40 00      00:01:48.448  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 58 78 90 d9 df 40 00      00:01:48.441  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 29 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7264 hours (302 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 d9 27 25 10 06  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x06102527 = 101721383

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 d0 38 0b 11 40 00      00:06:28.814  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 28 70 19 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 60 19 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 18 78 0a 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 10 20 0a 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 28 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7262 hours (302 days + 14 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 04 84 ec 96 06  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0696ec84 = 110554244

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 20 38 68 ec 96 40 00      00:17:45.395  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 30 50 5e a8 40 00      00:17:39.523  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:17:34.424  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 08 a8 60 ec 96 40 00      00:17:34.424  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:17:34.389  FLUSH CACHE EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7267         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

...
**UPDATE**

I did not find any bad sectors on any of my drive. Discovered some file corruption in Windows 10 that was corrected  but still the boot fails sometime.

**UPDATE**

Here is the recent output of my short smart test, Note that

**The Number of Power On Hours has Increased instead of decreasing if it were repressenting the remaining life-time of hard drive. What does it mean?**

```
 smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-50-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Travelstar Z5K500
Device Model:     HGST HTS545050A7E380
Serial Number:    TM85014C0KBUSM
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 72fc7e6b8
Firmware Version: GG2OAC90
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 22 13:08:32 2021 PKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 113) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   212   212   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       6713
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       7277
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       5160
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       131072
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       348
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   083   083   000    Old_age   Always       -       172408
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   176   176   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 9/49)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 33 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 33 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7268 hours (302 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 79 6f f2 60 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0060f26f = 6353519

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 c8 00 20 f2 60 40 00      00:01:39.821  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 e8 f0 50 9e 60 40 00      00:01:39.820  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 88 e8 48 a7 60 40 00      00:01:39.808  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 e0 50 9d 60 40 00      00:01:39.802  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 d8 d8 aa 60 40 00      00:01:39.792  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 32 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7265 hours (302 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 81 37 b4 60 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0060b437 = 6337591

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 c0 58 f8 b3 60 40 00      00:01:15.846  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 c0 50 b8 a1 60 40 00      00:01:15.831  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 48 48 b0 cd 60 40 00      00:01:15.831  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 40 e0 0c 14 40 00      00:01:15.816  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 48 38 40 8d 60 40 00      00:01:15.816  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 31 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7265 hours (302 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 61 33 89 07  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x07893361 = 126432097

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 02 90 60 33 89 40 00      01:06:25.973  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 0b 88 d0 ff d6 40 00      01:06:25.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 d0 fe d6 40 00      01:06:25.959  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 9f 78 a8 53 e4 40 00      01:06:25.936  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 c2 70 b0 fb d6 40 00      01:06:25.929  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 30 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7264 hours (302 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 11 7f da df 02  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x02dfda7f = 48224895

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 50 98 40 da df 40 00      00:01:48.485  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 90 ca 4c 20 40 00      00:01:48.459  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 58 88 e8 d9 df 40 00      00:01:48.449  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 80 ea 0d 27 40 00      00:01:48.448  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 58 78 90 d9 df 40 00      00:01:48.441  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 29 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7264 hours (302 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 d9 27 25 10 06  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x06102527 = 101721383

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 d0 38 0b 11 40 00      00:06:28.814  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 28 70 19 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 20 60 19 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 18 78 0a 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 10 20 0a 10 40 00      00:06:28.808  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7277         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7267         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Whatever is happening to that disk? 170000 load cycles but only 7200 hours of use

Comment: I got this laptop five years ago I am living in  hot area and was testing a game heavy on graphics by multiple starting and exiting before this apparent corruption occurred. I tried repairing filesystem in Windows 10 system with the problem repeating again Is my Hard rive dying a natural death or it suffered some damage that reduced its cycle and can its simple replacement suffice?

Comment: How much time my hard drive has?

Comment: We have no idea

Comment: Did it get thrown off a cliff?
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       131072